# An algorithm to assign the nearest postcode to a set of coordinates in R

Tags: r, algorithm, gis

My question is structured in two parts. I am looking for a solution in R:

**Part 1**

I have two sets of (x,y) coordinates - let's call these (x1, y1) and (x2, y2):

```
x1 <- c(1,2,4,6,7)
y1 <- c(5,2,4,7,8)

x2 <- c(5,3,4,2)
y2 <- c(8,1,2,4)
```

I want to calculate the Euclidean distance between the first coordinate in (x1, y1), i.e. (1, 5) with all the coordinates in (x2, y2), and then repeat this for the second coordinate in (x1, y1), and calculate all the Euclidean distance between this second set with all the coordinates in (x2, y2). I then want to repeat this until we have calculated it for all the coordinates.

What I did was to create a formula, and then use a lapply:

```
algo <- function(x, y)
{
  dist <- sqrt(((x2 - x)^2) + ((y2 - y)^2))
}

distances <- lapply(x1, algo, y = y1)
```

However, this returns five [1:5] numeric vectors. This was not what I was expecting - I was expecting it to return five [1:4] numeric vectors, since there are only 4 coordinates in (x2, y2).

I think what I did wrong was that I failed to account how R performs calculations on vectors with lapply, but I am not sure where the problem is. Can you provide a solution to what I am looking for?

**Part 2**

I have a set of postcodes that go with (x2, y2):

```
postcode <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
```

Assuming that we get Part 1 of the question correct, i.e. we can calculate the distances between the first set of coordinates with the second set of coordinates, what I want to do is to assign (x1, y1) with the nearest postcode.

What I wanted to do was to identify the minimum distance calculated in Part 1 (which I couldn't get it to work), and then identify the location of the minimum distance within the calculated vector, and then lookup the postcode. What can I do?

Many thanks for you time and kind attention - happy to elaborate if you have any questions about my question.

Comment: I don't think this makes sense: postcodes are not assigned by [Voronoi diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram)

Comment: This is an approximation that I am trying to do. The Ordnance Survey assigns a Northings and Eastings coordinates to all postcodes in the UK. I have a set of Northings and Eastings coordinates that do not map exactly to the Ordnance Survey's coordinates (as I assume a postcode would span multiple coordinates). Hence I want to make an approximation to get the nearest postcode given the Ordnance Survey's coordinates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lapply(x1, algo, y = y1)`, iterates over `x1` but not over `y1`. When trying to substract the vector `y1` to a vector `y2`, it throws an error because they don't have compatible length.

You should use `mapply` instead of `lapply` when you have more than 1 parameter:

```
distances <- mapply(algo, x1, y1, SIMPLIFY = F)
```

For the second question, just use `which.min()` on your distance set to find the closest:

```
algo <- function(x, y)
{
        dist <- which.min(sqrt(((x2 - x)^2) + ((y2 - y)^2)))
}
postcode[mapply(algo, x1, y1, SIMPLIFY = T)]
[1] "d" "b" "c" "a" "a"
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply - this was very helpful. To help me further understand, why is it the case that lapply doesn't work (apart from the fact that it does not work as well for functions with multiple arguments) - what is lapply trying to do in my specification stated in my question? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version using R's `sp` classes:

```
x1 <- c(1,2,4,6,7)
y1 <- c(5,2,4,7,8)

x2 <- c(5,3,4,2)
y2 <- c(8,1,2,4)

postcode <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")

library(sp)
library(rgeos)

x1 <- SpatialPoints(cbind(x1, y1))
x2 <- SpatialPoints(cbind(x2, y2))

postcode[apply(gDistance(x1, x2, byid = TRUE), 2, which.min)]
## [1] "d" "b" "c" "a" "a"
```